# How to find out that whether a point on a map is within a radius from user's present location on iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps, cllocationmanager, cllocationdistance

I am new to iOS and I have to make an application in which the the user will know its present location and will enter a value in Kilometers and I have to find out that whether another given pair of latitude and longitude (which give a location on map) is within the given range. Please suggest if we have any function which can used to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You obtain user location via [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) or via MapView's userLocation.
Then you may create a `CLRegion` and use it's `– containsCoordinate:` method, like:

```
CLRegion* region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:centerCoord radius:radius identifier:@""];
BOOL isInside = [region containsCoordinate:yourCoord]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation:(const CLLocation *)location
```

*CLLocationDistance* is a typedef for double (in meters)

Convert that to kilometers and compare it to the given value.